# Sci-fi horror film. Scientists discover a scary video beamed from the future

Tags: story-identification, horror

I don't have a lot about this movie. It's at least 15 years old. There was a group of scientists, they were trapped somewhere (some base). There was snow (I think). They were getting some signal with some stranger scary video and someone figured out that the signal is faster than light, so it's coming from the future. That's all I remember.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/154233/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Signal_(2007_film)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Darkness_(film)?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that's not all you remember :-)

Comment: @Valorum, hence the comment. They remember other things everytime I link them to your list!

Comment: Were they male or female scientists? What were they studying? Why was the video scary? Did any of them die? How did they figure out that the signal was from the future? Was it from years into the future or only a few hours/days/weeks/months? Was the movie in colour or black&white? Did it have a high budget or a low one? Was their any gore/nudity/foul language/violence/drug-taking? Which actors were in it? Do you remember any lines from the movie? Did everyone survive at the end? How did it end?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Travelers_(1964_film)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timescape?